# Which DBMS is better to manage billions rows?

Tags: database, backend

I have a database with 22 billions rows and create the reports delay too much, and I want to migrate to a DBMS that supports this amount of data.

Which DBMS can be used to manage billions of rows?

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Well, if you have this many rows - I *hope* you're not running your reports off the online production database .....

Comment: Off-topic because this could get into recommending a product; however, most RDBMS's can support large databases on properly sized hardware.